# Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit Error: Unable to load entities due to Network Outage

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am having the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXBJQ.png) only when I try to connect to our test CRM (Dynamics CRM 2016 - On Premise) with the Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit plugin for Visual Studio 2017 Professional. The plugin works fine on our production environment.

I have installed the toolkit following these steps [Install Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit with Visual Studio 2017](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365fordevelopers/posts/install-dynamics-365-developer-toolkit-with-visual-studio-2017), including Step 6 – Update the Toolkit dlls with more recent versions from the SDK (Optional). I'm using SDK 8.2 and I have referenced the [tool paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoomd.png).

Everything else except the Entities is getting loaded in CRM Explorer, I am able to deploy webresources just fine, but when I right click in the CRM Explorer and select Add Plugin I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sidf.png). Basically the same problem as described in [this thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/272953/problems-creating-plugin-using-visual-studio-2015-with-dynamics-365-developer-tools/775482), but I couldn't find a solution there.

It's good to mention here that both of our CRM environments (test and production) are behind a corporate proxy, which was our main suspect for this problem, but after checking the network it seems like the proxy is not blocking anything. Also I have system administrator rights on both environments. There might be some difference in the configuration between the two environments that is causing this problem, I just don't know what to look for. Has anyone experienced such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by installing Visual Studio 2015 and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohanKustner.DynamicsCRM2016DeveloperToolkitforVisualStudio2015) version of the plugin.